# Multitenancy Software design with ASP.NET MVC, WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, design-patterns, architecture, asp.net-web-api

I am launching my startup and i need to make a critical architecture choice.
I will provide a SAAS web application for my clients, they have different specific needs but the main purpose of the program is the same, automatically generating documents and pdf.

Technincally i choose ASP.NET MVC, WebAPI, EF Code First. Now I have a working proof of concept with only one project  (1 db, 1 asp.net mvc client, 1 asp.net webapi, 1service layer + 1 repository)

I will have one database for every client (easier to maintain, scale ...)

One WebFront for each client with personalized html/css templates and of course specific data/menu

Only one WebApi service exposing all services for each client,
For example /api/client1/, /api/client2/ with almost the same api calls but not the same data returned.

For each client a service layer (Class library dll) that stores business logic, data acess, POCO/DTO.

Each Webfront shares reference to specific service DTO/POCO.

I need of course my solution to scale horizontally, not vertically.

So is it a good choice?
Do you have any recommendation/better solution ?
Can I put All this in the same visual project ?
I really would like to have the service layer(business) in only one project, and  with good Object Oriented approach I can serve all my clients with common needs shared between all of them and specific one in derived objects.

Thanks for help

Comment: When you say: "one database for every client" and "one webfront for each client"... do you mean that you'll have as many webfronts and databases as there are clients? or one database/webfront for *ALL* clients?

Comment: I mean one database for every client, but i don't yet decided if all willl share the same schema or not.
And also one front per client, beacause each one will have specific data/menus to show, different authorisation/authentication and of course a branded html css template

Comment: For the data part there's this nice msdn article : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx (there used to be a Microsoft whitepaper on that as well but I can't seem to find it now)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316890/how-to-set-up-a-multitenancy-application-using-asp-net-mvc/25567005#25567005 for the MVC view resolution part